Any idea how to connect Spring Boot to Document Understanding from Oracle Cloud?
I'm trying to connect Spring Boot to Document Understanding Api, but I don't know how to do it.
I'm also using Maven as the Project Management Tools while working on the projects. If there's any dependencies that I can use so that easier to connect to Oracle Cloud api then please give me a brief or long tutor, thanks.
I'm expecting able to connect to Document Understanding
